# How could i insert an image into a div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tablezone.css">
    <script src="table.js"></script>  
</head>
<body> 
    <div id="divTable"; class="zone"></div>  
</body>
</html>
```

here is javascript code :

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src="/Tables/table.png";

var src = document.getElementById("divTable");
src.appendChild(img);
```

here is the css code:

```
body{
    background: url('/Tables/Riviera.jpeg');
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.zone{
    background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.7);
    width: 1000px;
    height: 600px; 
    margin-left: 200px;  
}
```

when I run the code on a web browser the div is displayed with no image inside it.

Comment: I check your code and its worked

Comment: I think the image path which you are mentioning might be wrong and hence you might not be able to see the image.. Working example (Image with external link): https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/OJyMoGw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script runs before `divTable` has been added to the DOM, so the line `document.getElementById("divTable")` returns `null`. Moving the `script` tag to the end of the body ensures that the `divTable` element is in the DOM before `getElementById` runs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tablezone.css">
</head>
<body> 
    <div id="divTable" class="zone"></div> 
    <script src="table.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i just changed the script element and  placed it where you said and everything works fine